# Capture last occurrence from multiple occurrences in Regex pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, toad

How can I capture the below desired capture? I did this way Regex `ONE.*(ONE.)` but it captures the whole string.

Notedpad++:

```
1 ONE;TWO;THREE;ONE;FOUR;FIVE
2 TEST
3 TEST
4 TEST
5 TEST
```

Desired Capture: If ONE has 1 match then return `ONE;TWO;THREE` else if `ONE` has two matches then return `ONE;FOUR;FIVE`.

Comment: Hi @Ryszard Czech, really appreciate your reply, can you conver it to https://www.regexpal.com? It doesn’t work in regexpal which compatible with what I’m using…Thank you.

Comment: Select PCRE option from the dropdown box.

Comment: Hi @Ryszard Czech yes it works when I changed to PCRE but when I do the pattern in Toad SQL doesn’t work, I don’t know why? SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Column,’ .*\KONE(?:(?!ONE).)*’) as NML from tbl

Comment: Hi Ryszard Czech it captures the whole string…Not the second occurrence…

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Column, '.*(ONE.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Hi Ryszard Czech, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `(?:ONE.*)?(ONE.*)` and retrieve your result from the first capturing group.

This regex will always try to match two ONEs in a line, but lets you access the part relevant to the second ONE. When there's only one that's the only part that matches.

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/ClPQUe/1).

Comment: Hi Aaron, the number of delimiter “;” is constant it’s always 5 (;) how can we call it say the value of the 3rd delimiter?

Comment: Disregarding the ONEs, `^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^;]*);` will have the value of the third field in its first capturing group

Comment: Hi @Aaron I prefer your pattern how can I rephrase the pattern if there are 50 (;) and I want to capture somewhere in 30th (;) without doing ^[^;]*; 30 times?

Comment: You can factorize the first 29 fields : `^(?:[^;]*;){29}([^;]*)`

Comment: Hi @Aaron, it works thank you? How can I accept this answer? Just click the arrow up right?

Comment: There's a check mark below the answers' score  to mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

In Toad SQL, use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Column, '.*(ONE.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

**EXPLANATION**

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ONE                      'ONE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

In Notepad++, use

```php
.*\KONE(?:(?!ONE).)*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/pR7uPM/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       matc reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ONE                      'ONE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ONE                      'ONE'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^.*\K\bONE\b.*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char 0+ times
- `\K\bONE\b` Forget what is matched so far, and  backtrack till the last occurrence of `ONE` to match it
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67vDtF/1)

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, thank you. But it doesn’t work with https://www.regexpal.com

Comment: @MitchelAraw You have to select PCRE in the dropdown box at the right top. Also select multiline to see all the matches.

Comment: If OP used `Oracle` tag correctly, [Oracle doesn't support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Perl-influenced-Extensions-in-Oracle-Regular-Expressions.html#GUID-2D2B8DEB-1343-4DA3-BBC1-5A5C79A5FC20) `\K`, `\b` and many other useful metacharacters.